# Why is my while loop returning undefined

Tags: javascript, while-loop

```
var names = ["Patrick", "Lizzy", "Walty"];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    console.log("My name is: " + names[i]);
};

while (names) {
    console.log("According to the while loop, my name is " + names[i]);
    var names = false;
};
```

This is the code that is printed out:

```
My name is: Patrick 
My name is: Lizzy 
My name is: Walty 
My name is: undefined
According to the while loop, my name is undefined
```

Why is the while loop returning "undefined" instead of each of the three names? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The value of `i` is `3` in the while loop, then you set it to `false`, which has no indexed properties. Hence the loop is executed only once.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes, ofcourse ; ).

Comment: I don't believe you're actually getting the message `My name is: undefined`. Is that really true?

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

1. JS does not use block scoping, so `i` is still valid and set to `3`.
2. JS uses type coercion, so `names` converted to a boolean is always true.

Because of that, your `while` loop is equivalent to:

```
var names = true; // coercion!
while (names) {
  console.log("According to the while loop, my name is " + names[3]);
  var names = false;
};
```

You should reset the counter before you get to the while loop, then increment it as you go along:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 3) {
  console.log("According to the while loop, my name is " + names[i]);
  ++i;
};
```

Remember that a `for` loop is just sugar for a `while` loop, allowing you to declare the counter at the beginning.

You can introduce `names.length` to replace your constant `3` and work with arrays more idiomatically:

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i += 1) {
  console.log("My name is: " + names[i]);
};

var i = 0;
while (i < names.length) {
  console.log("According to the while loop, my name is " + names[i]);
  ++i;
};
```

If you want to use modern features and get clever, you can use the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method on arrays:

```
names.forEach(function (name) {
  console.log("My name is: " + name);
});
```

This way, you don't have to worry about loops or indexes at all.

If `names` might not be an array, you can use ES6 syntax to loop over any iterable object:

```
for (const name of names) {
  console.log('My name is:', name);
}
```

Comment: The code above that is stated to be equivalent to the OP's code, is not actually equivalent.  In the OPs code the names[i] is attempting to dereference the original array (even though the array was coerced to a boolean in the while conditional), but the names[3] above is trying to dereference a true boolean value not the original array, since names has been set to true.

Comment: @RJM `names` is never set to true, although it is later set to `false`. The `while` condition the OP is using doesn't make much sense, as it will run once (with a bad index) then discard `names` entirely.

Comment: I'm referring to the code in this answer...names is set to true in this line:  `var names = true; // coercion!`

Comment: I'm trying to show how `names` will be coerced before entering the loop, although that example is kind of confusing. If you have an improvements, I'll accept the edit. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking your `for` loop prematurely. That's the reason. Also you don't need a `;` after the `}` in this case.

The reason why you are getting `undefined` is, by the time it comes to the `while` loop, the `i`'s value is `3`, which is out of the size of the `names` array.

The boolean value returned by `names` is always true, so it gets executed no matter what.

```js
var names = ["Patrick", "Lizzy", "Walty"];


for (var i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
  console.log("My name is: " + names[i]);
}
// Here the value of i is 3, which is out of bounds. So try using i-1:
while (names) {
  console.log("According to the while loop, my name is " + names[i-1]);
  var names = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `for()` loop exits, `i` will have a value of `3`. You then use that 3 as an index for you array, but your array only has values for keys 0->2